# Needed someone to double check my boolean equation to my schematic diagram

Tags: circuit-analysis, boolean-algebra

[image]

I wrote out the boolean equations for each output but after {(AB)' +C}', I wasn't too sure if it was right. Thank you in advance.

[image]

This is the truth table that I made so far if the boolean match the circuit.

Comment: Obviously, if C is 1 then the output is 0. So whatever equation you work out will be AND'd with /C. With slightly more inspection, you can see that if A is 0 then a 1 feeds into the last gate guaranteeing 0 output. So A must be 1. Already we have A C'. It takes very little more to realize that B must also be 1. So the output is A B C'. If I read you correctly, you got an equivalent expression.

Comment: @jonk Thank you for advice but what I was asking for is that if my boolean equation matched my diagram. For example  {{{(AB)’ + C}’. A}’ + C}’ which is X, if it was correct.

Comment: I think you wrote: \$ \overline{\overline{A B} +C}\$. Expanded, that is \$A B \overline C\$. Which is what I wrote. So I think those are the same things. So I agreed with you, without bothering to read your process. Did you want me to examine all of your steps? I didn't want to, since the result I saw looked right. But if that's your question I guess I could expend still more time to help prove your steps. I'm not sure that would be helpful, since you already appear to have gotten the right result in the end.